# How to get product IDs from a '^' separated list?

Tags: php, regex

I have a '^' separated list of product ID numbers, and I need to get just the product ID number, and then use it to query a SQL database. The product ID numbers are stored in the $_SESSION hash. For example:

`SKUS: jpn18726^gr172645^123746^17246^eu186726^...`

The code I can think of is something like this:

```
$prodmat = $_SESSION["product"];
if(preg_match("(\d+)(^\s*\d+)*", $prodmat) {
    $stmt = "select shipcode from materials where material='???'";
}
```

Basically, I want to extract the product ID numbers from the '^' separated list, and then use the product ID numbers to query the DB.

Comment: So did you try the code you can think of?

Comment: Is `jpn18726` a product ID or just `18726`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus jpn18726 is the full ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do some explosions:

```
$prod_list = 'SKUS: jpn18726^gr172645^123746^17246^eu186726';
$list_parts = explode(':', $prod_list); // separate the text
$prods = explode('^', trim($list_parts[1])); // trim and put the list in an array
print_r($prods);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => jpn18726
    [1] => gr172645
    [2] => 123746
    [3] => 17246
    [4] => eu186726
)
```

Now you can loop through the array with your query.

```
foreach($prods as $product) {
     $sql = "SELECT foo, bar, WHERE products WHERE id = ?";
     // bind the current product
     // do the query
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that OP's question is a bit ambiguous at the moment. I think that clarification of "just the product ID **number**" could sway your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be performing just one query if possible. If you are using mysqli, you can use the following code block, though I'll recommend pdo because it is easier when dealing with a variable number of placeholders.

This code does NOTHING to validate the input data. It assumes that your SESSION data is 100% trustworthy and reliably formatted.  If you need to validate, then you will want regex to do the validating.  ...perhaps something like `~^SKUS: [a-z\d]+(?:\^[a-z\d]+)*$~` if your ids only contain numbers and letters.

Code:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION["product"])) {
    // $_SESSION["product"] = 'SKUS: jpn18726^gr172645^123746^17246^eu186726';
    // "SKUS: " is fixed/constant, so just remove it by known substring position/length

    $params = explode('^', substr($_SESSION["product"],6));  // trim off leading substring BEFORE exploding

    $count = count($params);
    $csph = implode(',', array_fill(0, $count, '?'));  // comma-separated placeholders

    if(!$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `shipcode` FROM `materials` WHERE `material` IN ($csph);")){
        echo "Syntax Error @ prepare: " , $conn->error;  // do not echo error on public site
    }else{
        array_unshift($params, str_repeat('s', $count));  // prepend the type values string
        $ref = [];  // add references
        foreach ($params as $i => $v) {
            $ref[$i] = &$params[$i];  // pass by reference as required/advised by the manual
        }
        call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], $ref);    

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Error @ bind_param/execute: " , $stmt->error;  // do not echo error on public site
        } elseif (!$stmt->bind_result($shipcode)) {
            echo "Error @ bind_result: " , $stmt->error;  // do not echo error on public site
        } else {
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                // do something with $shipcode
            }
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Missing/Invalid product data";
}
```

If you need to identify your shipcodes with the corresponding id, then just add the `material` column to the `SELECT` clause and the `bind_result()` call.

All that said, if you can confidently validate/sanitize your `SESSION` data, you can avoid the convolution of a prepared statement and just write your `SELECT` query with `IN` in the `WHERE` clause like: `WHERE materials IN (' . implode("','", $params) . ')`.